# How to accept license agreement during docker build?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

How to write the Dockerfile that can pass yes to prompting license agreement?

1. under Dockerfile directory, `docker build -t "{user}/{tags}" .` then build failed.
2. `docker logs {container id}`, show message as below:

   ```
   Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
   debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
   debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
   debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
   Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer

   TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR 
   MICROSOFT SOFTWARE
   ...
   Do you accept the EULA license terms? [yes/no]
   ```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @Illuminati Yes, I answered my own question, check below !

Answer (score 12):

For me, the `ACCEPT_EULA=y` before the install did the job, like

```
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install PACKAGE -y
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with every package e.g. ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 8):

Follow by discuession here [issue: [16.04] debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/319).

I added these three lines of codes in Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND teletype

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
```

Finally I can build the docker image !

Comment: The second line renders the first line irrelevant.

Comment: You can also put it as part of the apt-get command e.g. DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 4):

I was able to agree to a license during the build process of a Dockerfile by piping the installation that required the confirmation with the `yes` command, which spams `y` or `yes` to any confirmation prompt (see [here](https://linuxhint.com/bash_yes_command/)). Before, my build process was still getting stuck on the `[yes/no]` prompt like you describe. Note, that the steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49065170/10476976) are still required. Without them, the yes command doesn't seem to be enough, as the build process still gets stuck on the `[yes/no]` prompt.

This is what I have in my dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND teletype
RUN yes | apt-get install <package>
```

With that, I can automatically accept prompts in the terminal:
[image]

It actually also works for these "debian confirmation dialogues" (don't know the correct term):
[image]

Maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution based on this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106553

1. Install the package manually first (i.e. on an existing container, on a local machine)

   ```
   $ apt-get install -y PACKAGE
   ```
2. Once it's installed, get the `debconf` setting for the license

   ```
   $ debconf-get-selections | grep PACKAGE
   PACKAGE    PACKAGE/license    string    y
   ```
3. Now to build the Docker image with a Dockerfile:

   ```
   ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
   RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections && \
       echo PACKAGE PACKAGE/license string y | debconf-set-selections && \
       apt-get install -y PACKAGE
   ```

You might need to install `debconf-utils` for `debconf-set|get-selections`.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Installed dependency:
`apt-get install -y expect`

Then execute:

```bash
/usr/bin/expect -<< EOS
    spawn /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start \
        --accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt
    expect eof
EOS
```

without expect the splunk start just got stuck when building the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

For installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer Ubuntu package in a Dockerfile, none of the above solutions work. What finally worked for me was this:

```
echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections \
&& DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score -6):

You can write a `-y` at the end of your line in the Dockerfile.

Example:

```
RUN         apt-get update
RUN         apt-get install netcat -y
```

Comment: I already add `-y` to every `apt-get` commands. :(   It's the same problem with this [issue](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/319), didn't success yet.